# Error With Pyinstaller installation and use

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
C:\Users\botta>pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- --------
altgraph                  0.17.3
pefile                    2023.2.7
pip                       23.2.1
pyinstaller               5.13.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2023.6
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.2

C:\Users\botta>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It says that pyinstaller is installed successfully but when I go to use it it gives the error above.